# Best way to load ~500 paragraphs plus options

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm just getting started and trying to make a simple app after going through some of the Google Codelabs. I wrote a Choose your own Adventure type of game. It consists of 500 paragraphs, and at the end of each paragraph is usually a choice of the next action to take (ie paragraph to load) and possibly some game logic. For now I am concentrating on the text only.

It seems simpler to make 500 text files and load up whatever file number is necessary, however it makes more sense to load ALL the paragraphs as the entire text takes up roughly 300Kb as a text file.

How would I even attempt this? I know I would need a text array and I file reader. I think it would be more work to format the paragraphs with a delineator to separate them, as it may be simpler to just create 500 files and write a While loop feeding my array.

That should fulfill my current objective, but when I want to add the choices at the end of the paragraphs, it seems as if a JSON or XML file that includes the text and choices would be better. I could not figure out how to even attempt this.

Example Paragraph: "You hear a horseman galloping and spin towards the sound. Do you have the skill of Forest Stealth? If you do, turn to 95. If you do not, turn to 234."